# Magento 2 how to set proper file and folder permission in localhost ubuntu 18?

Tags: magento2, cli, localhost, file-permissions, ubuntu

i'm

using 
magento 2 in local setup in ubuntu 18

when every time i run cmds

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
```

the file permission changed 
**how to give proper file permission in ubuntu local setup**

i already give permission with

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/wwww/html/myproject/
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/myproject/pub/
```

any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Magento Devdocs helps with this.
Take a look at:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html
I usually run:

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;

find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are the required permissions for magento 2:

sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;

sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;

sudo find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;

sudo find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;

sudo find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;